# Chrome Extensions for Firefox (Alternatives)

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, browser-addons, software-rec

I am looking for some extensions for Firefox which I learned to enjoy in Chrome, namely **Google Quick Scroll** and **Google Dictionary**. Are there equivalent extensions for Firefox?

Comment: Have you googled?

Comment: Of course did I do. No results for Quick Scroll and no comparable results for Dictionary (no tooltip on double-clicking a word).

Comment: [Quick Scroll for Firefox](https://superuser.com/questions/179911/quick-scroll-for-firefox)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tooltip on double-clicking a word: Dictionary Tooltip  1.6.1 https://addons.mozilla.org/pt-BR/firefox/addon/1171/

Comment: Although not as beautiful as the Chrome version this addon works as expected. If there really is no equivalent for the other extension I will accept your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'd like to check out: 
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/google-dictionary-and-google-t/

It has almost the same graphical interface and representation wit Google Dict. And I think it's more prompt than Dictionary Tooltip