# Quick Scroll for Firefox

Tags: productivity, google-chrome-extensions, firefox-extensions

Is there an equivalent to the Chrome **Quick Scroll** add-on for Firefox?

https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/okanipcmceoeemlbjnmnbdibhgpbllgc

This is a killer feature of the Chrome browsing environment, which I miss having reverted to back to Firefox for other reasons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no equivalent of "Chrome Quick Scroll" for Firefox, but there may be a workaround. You can try [Google chrome extensions manager](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/98440/) addon which will allow you to use Google Chrome extensions inside Firefox. I didn't try it but it deserves a try.

Comment: Well, I cannot get this working on Linux Mint 9, but it is a nice lead. Maybe someone else with more time/persistence can get this to work.

Comment: Apparently the addon doesn't exist anymore. thanks for the info @[DanielHershcovich](http://superuser.com/users/23297/daniel-hershcovich)

Answer (score 0):

Here's an extension: [Search quick scroll BETA](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/search-quick-scroll/). It is indeed beta, sometimes selects wrong text.

And scrolling won't work if you're using NoScript until you whitelist a site. Highlighting will work anyway.